# How can I trigger an alert in google analytics if there are some events I want to monitor

Tags: google-analytics

I have an app that sends events when something failed to google analytics. I can see the events, they all have the category `"* Failed"`, whit * meaning whatever part of code I want.

How can I make an automated alert that will send me an email on the google analytics website whenever there are new `* Failed` events? The problem is what to choose on the "Alert me when" section.

thanks.

[image: google analytics screenshot alert]

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do `Unique Events` or `Total Events` is greater than 0?

[image]

Comment: now I got it. It will send me an email if the total events (event = event with category containing "Failed") is more than zero.